# Azure IOT edge error pulling docker image of custom nodeJS module

Tags: gateway, azure-iot-edge

Hi I'm making an Azure IOT edge Gateway and I’m trying to install à custom module on it but I have this error:

Error calling Create module serverModule: Could not create module serverModule
caused by: No such image: MyDockerAzureContainerServer/serverModule:0.0.1-amd64) ....

but if I run

docker pull MyDockerAzureContainerServer/serverModule:0.0.1-amd64

it works!

BTW : I’m working on a winndows10 device running docker Linux containers

I really don’t get it thanks for any help.

deployment.json :

```
{
    "$schema-template": "2.0.0",
    "modulesContent": {
        "$edgeAgent": {
            "properties.desired": {
                "schemaVersion": "1.0",
                "runtime": {
                    "type": "docker",
                    "settings": {
                        "minDockerVersion": "v1.25",
                        "loggingOptions": "",
                        "registryCredentials": {
                            "Server Name": {
                                "username": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME_user",
                                "password": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_userPW",
                                "address": "server Name.azurecr.io"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "systemModules": {
                    "edgeAgent": {
                        "type": "docker",
                        "settings": {
                            "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0",
                            "createOptions": {}
                        }   
                    },
                    "edgeHub": {
                        "type": "docker",
                        "status": "running",
                        "restartPolicy": "always",
                        "settings": {
                            "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0",
                            "createOptions": {
                                "HostConfig": {
                                    "PortBindings": {
                                        "5671/tcp": [
                                        {
                                            "HostPort": "5671"
                                        }
                                        ],
                                        "8883/tcp": [
                                        {
                                            "HostPort": "8883"
                                        }
                                        ],
                                        "443/tcp": [
                                        {
                                            "HostPort": "443"
                                        }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "modules": {
                    "serverModule": {
                        "version": "1.0",
                        "type": "docker",
                        "status": "running",
                        "restartPolicy": "always",
                        "settings": {
                            "image": "${MODULES.serverModule}",
                            "createOptions": {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "$edgeHub": {
            "properties.desired": {
                "schemaVersion": "1.0",
                "routes": {
                    "serverModuleToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/serverModule/outputs/* INTO $upstream"
                },
                "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
                    "timeToLiveSecs": 7200
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(English is not my native language sorry)

Comment: are you using a private container registry (such as Azure Container Registry) or does your image reside in public Dockerhub?

Comment: I'm using a Azure Container Registry in deed

Comment: Do you have a `registryCredentials` in your deployment.json? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition#configure-modules

Comment: Yes I do and I know they are good because in azure I can see the image

Comment: can you post your entire deplyomen.json? (removing all passwords etc)

Comment: Yep, post it ^^

Comment: I assume "address": "server.azurecr.io" contains your actual ACR name, correct? (e.g. yourreg.azurecr.io) And your image of your module then looks like yourreg.azurecr.io/serverModule:0.0.1-amd64

Comment: yes I censored it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to run it :

I configured my docker to run windows containers and I created a dockerfile.**windows-amd64** on witch I run basic npm installations commands 
for **windows**.

Dockerfile.windows-amd64 :

```
FROM stefanscherer/node-windows:latest
RUN mkdir \app
WORKDIR /app

ONBUILD COPY package.json package.json
ONBUILD RUN npm install
ONBUILD RUN npm install {anny other specific dependencies} --production

ONBUILD COPY . .

CMD [ "node.cmd", "app.js" ]
```

once you have done that you need to add this file un the known platforms, to do so modify the module.json file of your projet and add the windows-amd64 line :

```
{
    "$schema-version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "",
    "image": {
        "repository": "{you're Server Name}.azurecr.io/{you're Module}",
        "tag": {
            "version": "0.0.1",
            "platforms": {
                "amd64": "./Dockerfile.amd64",
                "amd64.debug": "./Dockerfile.amd64.debug",
                "arm32v7": "./Dockerfile.arm32v7",
                "arm32v7.debug": "./Dockerfile.arm32v7.debug",
                "Windows-amd64": "./Dockerfile.windows-amd64"
            }
        },
        "buildOptions": []
    },
    "language": "javascript"
}
```

and finally you need to modify this line in the deployment.template.json :

```
[...]
 "modules": {
     "{you're Module}": {
         "version": "1.0",
         "type": "docker",
         "status": "running",
         "restartPolicy": "always",
         "settings": {
             "image": "${MODULES.{you're Module}.Windows-amd64}",
             "createOptions": {}
         }
     }
 }
[...]
```

And it should run fine.

Note that I Run now a NodeJS app on a Windows container on a Windows machine running docker Windows.

I leave this answer if it can help anyone feel free to contact me of you have any questions.