# Not able to deploy Node JS Module on windows container

Tags: node.js, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am able to create and pull image of IoT edge node js module from azure container registry but not run under windows container. also on azure portal showing it as module not reported by device

Comment: Without more details like the code; errors reported by the Edge runtime; steps you have taken to test the issue, it will be very hard to get help with this question. Can you add more details?

Comment: I referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360179/azure-iot-edge-error-pulling-docker-image-of-custom-nodejs-module and everything worked except my issue

Comment: You need to add more details about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Only C# and C modules are supported on Windows containers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-node-module#solution-scope